# What has happened to the views count recently?

Tags: bug, views

In [this question](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/790/what-is-the-meaning-of-anadew/) I even received an answer, but the view count is still 1 (one), even after a forced reload of the question. I am also suspicious over very low view counts on other questions, is there something going wrong here?

[image: One view on answered question]